# Nodal analysis question (with supernode)

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am studying for the exam, and found this question. [image]

Now, I know that you have to apply a supernode, but I don't know how. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why do you think it requires supernode analysis?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$V_2=-20i_\Delta$$ $$V_1=10$$

$$\frac{V_2-V_o}{20}=\frac{V_o}{40}+\frac{V_o-V_1}{10}~\Rightarrow~7V_o-2V_2=40$$

$$\frac{V_o-V_1}{10}+\frac{V_2-10}{30}=-i_\Delta~\Rightarrow~6V_o-V_2=80$$

$$V_o=24~\text{Volts}$$
$$V_2=64~\text{Volts}$$